# How can I ask for input based on items in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to make a loop that asks for the rainfall of each month, with the months stored into a list. How can I make 1 loop that will ask for input of the rainfall for each month by pulling each month from the list?

example:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March"]
rainfall = input("What is the rainfall for ", months[0])
```

how can i do that for each month with 1 loop?

Comment: This should be a basic `for` loop https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
rainfall = []
for month in months:
    answer = int(input("What was the rainfall in {}?".format(month)))
    rainfall.append(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about string formatting. There are several ways (`%`, `.format()`, and f-strings), but my favorite would be `.format()` which would look like:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March"]
rainfall = input("What is the rainfall for {}".format(months[0]))
```

Then to repeat the process for all months would could look something like this:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March"]
rainfall = [input("What is the rainfall for {}?\n>>>".format(month)) for month in months]
```

Where I added some nice formatting with a `\n` newline character, and an obvious prompt of `>>>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and a list that will keep taken rainfall answers from user.
This will loop for all elements in months list.

```py
months = ["January", "February", "March"]
rainfalls = []
for month in months:
    rainfall = input("What is the rainfall for " +  month+ "\n")
    rainfalls.append(rainfall)
print(rainfalls) #python3
```